# how to select minimum time and max time from sql vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, time, max, min

ok now i figured it out and it works for me, this is the answer i figured it out:

```
 SELECT        pno, attdate, MAX(atttime) AS attime
    FROM            att
    WHERE        (atttime >= '13:00') AND (atttime <= '23:59') 
    GROUP BY pno, attdate  


SELECT        pno, attdate, MIN(atttime) AS attime
        FROM            att
        WHERE        (atttime >= '00:00') AND (atttime <= '12:59') 
        GROUP BY pno, attdate
```

============================================
big thank to **user2342436**, I figured out the answer due to ur code. Thanks.
=========================================== =
I have a Table "att" which contains 3 columns "pno" "attdate" and "atttime", the data in as the following:

```
pno |     attdate   |      atttime
1       2015/01/15      07:02 
1       2015/01/15      07:03
1       2015/01/15      07:04
1       2015/01/15      13:01
1       2015/01/15      13:05
1       2015/01/15      13:07
2       2015/01/15      07:05 
2       2015/01/15      07:06
2       2015/01/15      07:08
2       2015/01/15      13:15
2       2015/01/15      13:16
2       2015/01/15      13:18
```

what i wantn is to select the min(atttime) if it AM and max(atttime) if it PM where the date i picked by datetimepicker. so the result must be like:

```
 pno    |     attdate   |      atttime
    1       2015/01/15      07:02 
    1       2015/01/15      13:07
    2       2015/01/15      07:05 
    2       2015/01/15      13:18
```

I am using vb.net 2008 & Sql server 2008.
what i want is to select min(atttime) if "atttime" is AM which is between 00:00 and 12:59, and select max(atttime) if "atttime" is PM which is between 13:00 and 23:59. I hope its more clear, I am sorry for bad english.
Please help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question , the following query should work:-

> select pno,attdate,min(atttime) attime from att group by pno,attdate 
>   union 
>   select pno,attdate,max(atttime) atttime from att group by pno,attdate

Please let me know if something else is required.

Comment: sorry, it didn't work for me, it gives me a result but not what i want, what i want is to select min(atttime) if "atttime" is AM which is between 00:00 and 12:59, and select max(atttime) if "atttime" is PM which is between 13:00 and 23:59. I hope its more clear, I am sorry for bad english.